# Angular if-then-else conditionals

Tags: angular, binding, angular2-changedetection

### Questions

I'm trying to show a spinner while a search service is busy retrieving and filtering results.  I figured that the newer Angular syntax for `*ngIf` that lets you have an else condition in addition to the if condition would be the way to go.  But whenever I start typing, the spinner correctly shows up, quickly followed by the error in the console complaining about a value changing after change detection ran.

- How can I correct this issue?
- Isn't the whole point of binding to have changes to component members/properties be reflected in the view?  Why wouldn't change detection take care of this rather than complaining about my timing?

### Component

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-help-search',
  templateUrl: './help-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./help-search.component.scss'],
  providers: [HelpSearchService]
})
export class HelpSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  searching: boolean;
  helpItems: Observable<HelpItem[]>;
  private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(
    private alertService: AppLevelAlertService,
    private helpSearchService: HelpSearchService,
    private router: Router) { }

  /**
   * Push a search term into the observable stream.
   */
  search(term: string): void {
    this.searching = true;
    this.searchTerms.next(term);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.helpItems = this.searchTerms
      .debounceTime(300)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(term => term
        ? this.helpSearchService.search(term)
        : Observable.of<HelpItem[]>([])
      )
      .catch(error => {
        this.alertService.errorOccurred.emit(new Error(error._body.error));
        return Observable.of<HelpItem[]>([]);
      })
      .finally(() => this.searching = false);
  }

  gotoHelpItem(helpItem: HelpItem): void {
    this.router.navigateByUrl(helpItem.url.toString());
  }

}
```

### Component Template

```js
<div id="search-component">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="search-box">Search for help topics: </label>
    <input type="text" #searchBox id="search-box" (keyup)="search(searchBox.value)" style="display: block; width: 100%; font-size: 20pt; height: 25pt" />
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="searching; then spinner else searchResults"></div>
  <ng-template #spinner>
    <span class="spinner spinner-lg">
      Loading...
    </span>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template #searchResults>
    <div *ngFor="let helpItem of helpItems | async" (click)="gotoHelpItem(helpItem)" class="search-result">
      <app-help-item [helpItem]="helpItem"></app-help-item>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

[image]

### What I've tried

I noticed that setting `this.searching` to `false` in the `.finally` predicate is what is causing this problem.  Instead of this approach, I tried subscribing to `this.helpItems` and in the `next` predicate setting `this.searching` to `false`.  This correctly removes the spinner when the results come back.  But unfortunately, this still doesn't work because the for loop does not take the spinner's place.  Both `ng-templates` disappear once the results come back.

Comment: you are not subscribing to the data. what is that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to have the help items show up in the view.  It shows up just fine in the view if I don't include a spinner.  But I'm trying to have the spinner be present until the search results are rendered.  Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach to solve this problem.  Instead of using the new `*ngIf` if-then-else conditionals to decide which `ng-template` to render, I chose to overlay the spinner and use css to control its visibility.  Here is the altered approach that works quite well for me:

### Component

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { AppLevelAlertService } from '../alerts/app-level-alert.service';
import { HelpItem } from '../help-item';
import { HelpSearchService } from '../help-search.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-help-search',
  templateUrl: './help-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./help-search.component.scss'],
  providers: [HelpSearchService]
})
export class HelpSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('overlay') overlay: ElementRef;

  searching: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
  helpItems: Observable<HelpItem[]>;

  private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(
    private alertService: AppLevelAlertService,
    private helpSearchService: HelpSearchService) {
    this.searching.subscribe(searching => this.overlay.nativeElement.style.display = searching ? 'block' : 'none');
  }

  /**
   * Push a search term into the observable stream.
   */
  search(term: string): void {
    this.searching.next(true);
    this.searchTerms.next(term);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.helpItems = this.searchTerms
      .debounceTime(300)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(term => {
        const results = term
          ? this.helpSearchService.search(term)
          : Observable.of<HelpItem[]>([]);
        return results;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.alertService.errorOccurred.emit(new Error(error._body.error));
        return Observable.of<HelpItem[]>([]);
      });
    this.helpItems.subscribe(thing => this.searching.next(false));
  }

}
```

### Template

```js
<div id="search-component">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="search-box">Search: </label>
    <input type="text" #searchBox id="search-box" (keyup)="search(searchBox.value)" />
  </div>
  <div #overlay id="overlay">
    <span class="spinner spinner-lg">
      Loading...
    </span>
  </div>
  <app-help-item *ngFor="let helpItem of helpItems | async" [helpItem]="helpItem"></app-help-item>
</div>
```

### Styling

```
#search-box {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20pt;
  height: 25pt
}

#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  z-index: 2;
  .spinner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transofrm: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
```